# Get the last alphanumerics string except the first char

Tags: regex

This is a the output that I have: `ZigBee:uio:ah.app.22732267579231878-1:xyz45465465a`, I want get `xyz45465465a` using regex so I'm using this regex `\:([A-Za-z1-9]*)$` but the result is `:xyz45465465a`.
I don't want the colon, how can I do?

Comment: Then why dont you just  try remove the `:` from the regex as well

Comment: put the colon inside a positive lookahead. or print  only the group index 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you put in the regex string, it will be captured an a match. If you do not to capture any symbols, just do not put them into a regex.

In your case, it is as simple as removing the `\:` from the beginning of a pattern.

```
([A-Za-z1-9]*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The match is:

[image]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TZzZpezFu-nQ8mcn)